# Bluetooth speaker outputLatency retuning wrong value at first time

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth, latency, avaudiosession

Bluetooth speaker connected to my iOS device, when i fetch Latency for the first time using below code :

In **viewDidLoad**

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {

        try self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try self.audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudio Session Error ")
    }
```

Get Latency :

```
 print("Latency :",audioSession.outputLatency) // Latency : 0.0912471637129784
```

Now i'm turnOff bluetooth speaker and turnOn again same code will give me this result :

```
print("Latency :",audioSession.outputLatency) // Latency : 0.159999996423721
```

So My question is why this variation is happening when first time bluetooth speaker is connect to device? Is there is anything i can do in coding to get **0.159999996423721** value.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

**UpdateCode**

I add below code for setting `mesurment` but nothing is changed.

```
do {
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
   }catch {
        fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Measurement")
   }
```

Note: I'm using JBL Flip 3 bluetooth speaker

Comment: did you try to AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement mode ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya no i have no idea about `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement`

Comment: `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.measurement)`  There are likely audio filters and hardware sample buffers that affect latency, but these are opaque to the app and may differ between device hardware models see this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25197

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thanks for your reply, i'll check with `measurement`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i added `measurement ` but nothings changed